# How to check whether the database dictionary changed?

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, dictionary

In my application I have to operate on several dictionaries. Few of them contain hundreds of records. I do not want to read the dictionary every time you start the application, because it is time-consuming (the data is accessed remotely via web service) and content dictionaries does not change very often. So I store copies of dictionaries in local cache.

What is the best way to check whether the data in the dictionary have changed and whether I should update the local cache?
I do not have the possibility of modifying the structure of database dictionaries (there are no timestamps).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SqlDependency` Class and receive notifications when the data is changed in the database.

```
void Setup()
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT Key, Value FROM dbo.SomeTable", 
        connection))
    {

        var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        dependency.OnChange += new
           OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Process the DataReader.
        }
    }
}

void OnDependencyChange(object sender, 
   SqlNotificationEventArgs e )
{
   // Something has changed 
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement SqlDependency in web service? And how to check whether a particular client has got most current data?

Comment: The server would have to initiate the request to the client in that case